# Internal compiler error integrating jabber-net with Unity3d

Tags: c#, xmpp, unity-game-engine

After importing the jabber-net dlls from [here](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/downloads/list) into my project and running

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using jabber;
using jabber.client;
using jabber.connection;

public class XMPP : MonoBehaviour {

    jabber.client.JabberClient jC;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
        jC = new JabberClient();
    }
}
```

Unity complains with:

> Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:
>   Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'jabber.connection.XmppStream' from assembly 'jabber-net, Version=2.1.0.710, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=924c5b18328d6f09'.

I have read that others (a very select few) have managed to get jabber-net integrated with their Unity code. Could anybody shed some light on how this could be done or point me to an alternative library? I would very much like to be able to use XMPP in my project.

Thanks

*Edit*

Thanks @Calvin for providing your helpful response and helping me drill down to the problem.

Steps to resolution:

1. Compile the dlls in monodevelop after stripping out System.Drawing and System.Windows.Form (Change build target to be library instead of executable)
2. Import the dlls in the Plugins folder (not a random folder)
3. Change the Unity build target to be Net 2.0 (not Net 2.0 subset) and instruct it to strip bytecode
4. Delete the SystemAssemblies folder to force a recompile

*Postmortem*

And ... this approach appears to ultimately fail. Compiling to ios seems to break the dependency chain with ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.Interlocked:CompareExchange (jabber.protocol.ProtocolHandler&,jabber.protocol.ProtocolHandler,jabber.protocol.ProtocolHandler)' while running with --aot-only.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using the Mono DLLs? I believe Unity is based on Mono and not the Microsoft .NET framework.

Comment: Yes I am using the Mono DLLs.

Comment: The jabber-net site doesn't say which versions of .Net it supports. You may have to compile it from source in MonoDevelop and see if there are build options to target .Net 2.0.

Comment: I built it using gmcs which should target .Net 2.0. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was just able to compile the 2005-jabber-net solution in MonoDevelop and add it to a Unity 3.5.6 project without Unity generating a compiler error.

The solution had references to System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms, which Unity doesn't support.  I removed those, changed the compile target to "Library", and copied the 2005-jabber-net.dll, netlib.Dns.dll, and zlib.net.dll into the Unity project.

Your sample code compiled and ran when attached to a GameObject, but I didn't test further.

edit: Just realized this assembly may require Unity Pro, since .Net socket access is restricted in the free version of Unity.

double edit: I take that back, just checked their product comparison chart and now .Net sockets are listed as available in the free version of Unity.

Comment: Thanks for trying this @Calvin. I attempted to do the same on my end:

1. Remove System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms references
2. Change target to Library
3. Set configuration to Release
4. Set the framework to build for as Mono 2.0

When I copy the dlls to the unity project I now get:

Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' from assembly 'xmpp'.
  
Any ideas?

Comment: Also, I should mention that I am in fact using a Unity Pro license.

Comment: I think I found the issue.  The jabber dlls need to be under the Plugins folder in your Unity project (Assets/Plugins/jabber/*.dll. That changes the compilation order, but I don't know why that fixes it.

Comment: Tried this just now per your suggestion. Same error. As a dumb sanity check, what are the sizes of your dlls? My 2005-jabber-net.dll file is 612352 bytes.

Comment: Here are my release dlls: https://www.box.com/s/0vmv8kl63j28kaywrxdc Also, I'm compiling and running on OSX and my system installed mono version is 2.10.9.

Comment: Same error but this helps. Now at least I know I wasn't building the dlls improperly.

Comment: Now we're getting into voodoo, but try closing Unity, delete the Library/ScriptAssemblies folder in your project, and reopen Unity. That should force scripts to recompile.

Comment: Still no dice. I also tried making an entirely new barebones project. Another differentiating factor is that I am still using a trial build of Unity3d Pro. Is it possible that that is affecting something? The unity version I am using is 3.5.6f4. Appreciate all of your help thus far by the way!

Comment: In "Project Settings->Player" change the "Api Compatibility Level" to ".NET 2.0" and if you are building for iOS or Android change Stripping Level to "Strip ByteCode". And it looks like the build doesn't work for Web Player.

Comment: Tried this as well actually. I'm tempted to just write C code and make it a unity plugin i guess if this doesn't sort itself out.